# What is a gremlin?

Tags: harry-potter, fan-fiction

When I google it, it finds me Dobby and a Goblin but that doesn't seem to answer my question.

On the Harry Potter Wiki it talks about the

> "The Gremlins were Hogwarts’ current group of mischief makers and
>   rascals, reminiscent of the Marauders"

**What are Gremlins?**

Comment: Well, you've got me confused as well, because I don't know what you're asking... because it sounds like you're asking about creatures (which Dobby and Goblins are not gremlins, I don't think the word is ever used for a critter), and the article you're talking about young wizards.

Comment: [This is a gremlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremlin), by the way.

Comment: I felt my answer was pretty convincing. Is there anything else you'd want me to address before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 11):

I believe your confusion stems from the use of the term [gremlin](http://jspotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gremlins) as part of the [**James Potter fan fiction books**](http://jspotter.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) where it's used to describe a group of student troublemakers.

> *Hogwarts’ current group of mischief makers and rascals, reminiscent of the Marauders; regarded as “scoundrels with honor” by Merlin. Known members include:*
>
> *Ted Lupin (leader)
>
> Noah Metzker
>
> Petra Morganstern
>
> Sabrina Hildegard
>
> Damian Damascus
>
> James S. Potter*

The term "[gremlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremlin)" features in **none of the canon books or any of the supplementary materials.**